# AVPlayerLayerの角を丸くするには？

Tags: ios, objective-c, 動画

[**Paper by FiftyThree App**](https://www.fiftythree.com/paper)
の初回起動時に表示されるようなVideoViewを作りたいと思っています。

そこで自分で単純なソースコードを組んでみました。

https://github.com/kawai-hiroyuki/KHFVideoViewBeta

しかし、私の作ったのはViewが角が丸い四角形になりません。

通常ならUIView.layerに

```
layer.cornerRadius = 16.0;
```

というコードを追加すれば、UIViewでは角が丸くなるのですが、反応しません。

どなたかアドバイスをいただけませんか？

Comment: みなさんのアイデアを元に自分のコードを更新しました。
もし同じ問題が発生したら、ここをみてください。[ソースコード](https://github.com/kawai-hiroyuki/KHFVideoViewBeta)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

あまりきれいなコードではありませんが、`cornerRadius`を利用する場合のサンプルです。

```
layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
layer.masksToBounds = YES;

// Layerのboundsをビデオのサイズに合わせる
CGSize videoSize = [[[_videoPlayer.currentItem.asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] naturalSize];
CGRect bounds = layer.bounds;
bounds.size = CGSizeMake(bounds.size.width, bounds.size.width * (videoSize.height / videoSize.width));
layer.bounds = bounds;
```

Comment: このやり方だとVideoのサイズとUIViewのサイズをあわせるので背景に違和感がないですね。このやり方を探していました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

CAShapeLayer を使うのがオススメです

```
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:20];
CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
layer.frame = rect;
layer.path = path.CGPath;
self.layer.mask = layer;
```

と

Comment: すいません、上記のコードをどの部分に追加すればいいのかわかりません。

Comment: -drawRect: に追加する方かよろしいと思います、View のサイスが変われる時もあるかもしれません

Comment: あ〜なるほど！-drawRect: ですか！こういうやり方もあるんですね。ありがとうございます。